# NancyFx FluentValidation issue

Tags: c#, nancy, fluentvalidation

I am developing a web framework with Nancy and I chose to use FluentValidation.

The models and validators are in the same Assembly, other than the main [App.Core (models and validators) -> App.Web (bootstrapper, modules, etc)]

I tried to add the bootstrapper AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.AddAssembliesToScan ("App.Core"); but without results.

What can I still do?

---

My model and validator:

```
using System;
using FluentValidation;

namespace App.Core.Modules.Account
{
    public class AccountLoginModel : BaseModel
    {
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountLoginValidator : AbstractValidator<AccountLoginModel>
    {
        public AccountLoginValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Username).NotNull().NotEmpty().Length(1, 64).Matches("[A-Z]*");
            RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotNull().NotEmpty().Length(8, 64).Matches("[A-Z]*");
        }
    }
}
```

---

My NancyModule

[...]

```
        Post["/login"] = x =>
        {
            var m = this.BindAndValidate<AccountLoginModel>();

            if (!ModelValidationResult.IsValid)
            {
                Model.BaseModel.AddError("Login errors...");
                Model.BaseModel.ReturnUrl = this.Request.Url;
                Model.Users = m;
                return View["Shared/Account/Login", Model];
            }
        };
```

[...]

---

My Bootstrapper

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{
            AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.AddAssembliesToScan("App.Core");
            [...]
}
```

---

Thank you all!

Comment: What errors are you seeing? What doesn't work? Are exceptions thrown? What are they?

Comment: The validation result is always true. I'm using latest nuget packages..

Comment: well, I don't know if that helps - but when using StructurMap, all I have to do is register all validators in IoC, Nancy picked that up. I assume that will be the case with TinyIoc

Comment: Did you try @chester89's suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately, AddAssembliesToScan doesn't exist in nancy 2.0